# How to cancel a started drag operation in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

I'm, using a NSTableView that supports drag drop. The underlying array may be asynchronously refreshed which calls [tableview reloadData]. When this happens I'd like to cancel a pending drag to avoid dragging around invalid source data. Any way to do that other than temporarily blocking tableView:validateDrop:proposedRow:proposedOperation: ?